# Discriminant of differential equation

Tags: functions, discriminant

I am aware of what the discriminant ($b^2-4ac$) means in relation to a function $f(x)$ when referring to the number of real roots.
$$\begin{align}
b^2-4ac&=0& &\longrightarrow &&\text{ two equal roots} \\
b^2-4ac&>0& &\longrightarrow &&\text{ two distinct roots} \\
b^2-4ac&<0& &\longrightarrow &&\text{ no roots}
\end{align}$$

However, does this change when referring to differential equations?

I read that $f'(x) > \text{or} = 0$ signifies that the $f'(x)$ has two equal roots or **no roots** (as written on the answer sheet, circled line)

Why is this the case?

(below are specific questions and their answers)

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: @rae306 an example of a function? :)

Comment: No, I don't understand the link with differential equations, so a differential equation.

Comment: @rae306 for instance, if f'(x)=$3x^2+2x$

Comment: @rae306 I actually found a specific question, but it's from a textbook. Am I allowed to add a photo into the question? Or will the question be closed?

Comment: no you can do that, please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$, that means that either $f'(x)>0$ for all $x$ **or** $f'(x)\geq 0$ for all $x$. In the first case, the graph lies completely under/above the $x$-axis (therefore it has no roots). In the second case, the graph touches the $x$-axis (therefore has two equal roots).

If the translate this into discriminant-talk: we must have $$\Delta=b^2-4ac=4p^2-12pq\leq 0 \iff p^2\leq 3pq$$

Comment: However, isn't the rule of discriminants that $f(x) > 0$ means two distinct roots, and for $f(x) = 0$, two equal roots? Also, what I do not understand is that on the answers it saids $4p^2-12pq < or = 0$, therefore the opposite of what you wrote?

Comment: No $f(x)>0$ means no roots, because it lies above the $x$-axis.. Sorry, I made a mistake on the second thing, I will correct :)

Comment: Oh right! Because delta $>0$ means two distinct roots, but $f(x)>0$ means no roots, correct? I was mixing the two up. Thank youu